# mapping all of Latin America with rworldmap

Tags: r, maps, geospatial, spatial, rworldmap

I am trying to plot some data for different countries in Latin America using the rworldmaps package. When including mapRegion='latin america', Mexico is cut off...is there any way to include Mexico other than by overriding using ylim and xlim? Thanks.

```
library(rworldmap)  
df <- NULL  
df$country <- c("Brazil","Mexico","Argentina")  
df$code<-c("BRA", "MEX", "ARG")  
df$popsize<-c(1000, 5000, 200)  
df<-as.data.frame(df)  
sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map( df, joinCode = "ISO3", nameJoinColumn = "code")  
mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot="popsize", mapRegion='latin america')
```

Comment: Do you want only Mexico to be added or are you including all countries from Mexico south?  In other words, is there a region western hemisphere and you can delete Canada and the United States?

Comment: All countries from Mexico south. Unfortunately, looks like region has to be set to one of the following: "eurasia", "africa", "latin america", "uk",
"oceania", "asia".  That's what I was hoping for - some way around this, or even just deleting the US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to select out the countries you are interested in, get the bounding box for these using the `bbox` function, and then use that to specify the xlim and ylim.

Continuing from after your code:

```
#select out your countries
sPDFmyCountries <- sPDF[sPDF$NAME %in% df$country,]
#use the bbox to define xlim & ylim
mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot="popsize", xlim=bbox(sPDFmyCountries)[1,], ylim=bbox(sPDFmyCountries)[2,])
```

If you wanted just to display the boundaries of the countries you have (i.e. if you had all of the Latin American countries in your data) you could do :

```
mapCountryData(sPDFmyCountries, nameColumnToPlot="popsize")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Any chance you could include us Mexicans in 'Latin America' in the next version...LOL?

Comment: certainly! Apologies for any offence caused by cutting your country in half ;-)